# My list button is not getting displayed when I use Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have been using jQuery Mobile to develop my web app. I have recently written a small piece of code which will take some some text and put it in the form of list but it is displaying as links.

This code is supposed to dynamically create buttons yet it is coming in the form of links:

```
function myFunction()
{
    $("#listview1").empty();

    // This will get the data
    $.get("#",function(data){
        $(data).find('UserProfile').each(function(index){

        // This is the real part this part is supposed to create the button
        $("<li data-theme='a'>"+
            "<a href='#page6' data-transition='slide' onclick='myFunction2(this)'>" +
            $(this).find('LoginId').text() + " " +
            $(this).find('FirstName').text() + " " +
            $(this).find('EmailID').text() +
            "</a>" + "</li>").appendTo("#listview1");
        });
    });

    var count=0;
    $("#listview1").children().each(function(){
        $(this).attr('id','li'+count);
        $(this).addClass("libutton");
        ++count;
    });
}
```

The primary problem is that when I use this to dynamically display buttons in jQuery Mobile it is coming in the form of links and not buttons.

Answer (score 0):

When you add content dynamically to a jQuery Mobile element you have to call **[refresh](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh)** on it:

```
$("#listview1").listview('refresh');
```